# How do I create an Open With Dialog in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a app that creates jpg images. Now I want to open a dialog which shows all the possible apps which can open a jpg image. When I tap on one of the apps in the dialog the tapped app should be opened and get the jpg image as parameter.

Here such a dialog from another app:

[image]

The dialog above shows all the apps where I can open my jpg image with.

**How do I create and use such a dialog in iOS?**

Comment: See `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: @maddy Could you be more specific?

Comment: @maddy, I think you meant UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: @user523234 Yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/), there are two methods:

`presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem`  and `presentOpenInMenuFromRect`

Quite simple to use, first create and initialize an instance of `UIDocumentInteractionController`:

```
self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:yourFilePathURL];
```

Next present the open-in dialog using either one of the above mentioned methods.

Comment: Is there a desktop version of this? I'm trying to show the "Open With" dialog for a path.