# Launch path/url with "Choose Application" dialog

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-foundation

If you right click on an item, then hover over "Open With", then you see "Other". Clicking that shows a dialog, which lists the "recommended applications" (which were seen in the first "open with" context menu) and now it shows some others too. Image is below.

Is there a way i can launch a path/url into this dialog? If url then it offers firefox, and safari, etc.

I saw this was possible on iOS but I can't find the desktop equivalent: [How do I create an Open With Dialog in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139009/how-do-i-create-an-open-with-dialog-in-ios)

Image of choose app dialog:

[image]

Comment: What does "launch a path/url into this dialog" mean?

Comment: Take a look at LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType and the other Launch Services functions.

Comment: I don't understand what to "launch a path/url into this dialog" mean, either.

Comment: Like I want to supply to a function `/blah/blah/blah.png` and it will show the dialog box and allow me to pick an app to open it with. Or if i supplied `blah.com` it will show me all the internet browsers i can open it with in the dialog. Thanks @jtbandes and El Tomato

Comment: Tahnks jtbandes and @ElTomato

Comment: You might also want NSSharingServicePicker

Comment: Thanks checking right now @jtbandes

Comment: What are you developing?  Are you developing a stand-alone desktop application?  If you want to have your application listed with 'Open With' for a png file, that's possible.  But there's a big price since PNG isn't your own format.

Comment: Thanks @ElTomato very much for your attn. An addon for firefox :) I uploaded a youtube screencast of it working in Windows :) https://github.com/Noitidart/LaunchyFx/issues/1#issuecomment-138005163